# PySpark Distinct List of Each of the Keys from an RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I'm sure this is simple, but I keep having issues. I have an RDD with key value pairs. I want a distinct list of just the keys. I'll share the code and examples. Thank you in advance!

## RDD Example

```
>>> rdd4.take(3)
[[(u'11394071', 1), (u'11052103', 1), (u'11052101', 1)], [(u'11847272', 10), (u'999999', 1), (u'11847272', 10)], [(u'af1lowprm1704', 5), (u'am1prm17', 2), (u'af1highprm1704', 2)]]
```

## Tried / Didn't Work

```
rdd4.distinct().keys()
rdd4.map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x))).keys().distinct()

[(u'10972402', 1), (u'10716707', 1), (u'11165362', 1)]
```

## Preferred Structure

```
[u'11394071', u'11052101', '999999', u'11847272', u'am1prm17', u'af1highprm1704']
```

Comment: What about keys `11052103` and `u'af1lowprm1704`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can for example:

```
rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).keys().distinct()
```

Comment: Works great thank you! Makes sense using the flat map.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flatMap` to get the keys from inner tuples and then call `distinct` on the result `RDD`:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([[(u'11394071', 1), (u'11052103', 1), (u'11052101', 1)], [(u'11847272', 10), (u'999999', 1), (u'11847272', 10)], [(u'af1lowprm1704', 5), (u'am1prm17', 2), (u'af1highprm1704', 2)]])

rdd.flatMap(lambda x: [k for k, _ in x]).distinct().collect()
# [u'999999', u'11394071', u'11847272', u'af1highprm1704', u'11052101', u'af1lowprm1704', u'am1prm17', u'11052103']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want just the distinct values from the key column, and you have a dataframe you can do:

```
df.select('k').distinct()
```

If you have only the RDD, you can do

```
rdd.map(lambda r: r[0]).distinct
```

Assuming tha the key is your left column